# How update a innerHTML of a <label> in Prototype by "for" attribute?

Tags: html, radio-button, label, prototypejs, innerhtml

I have this radio generate by a framework, how update the "asa" text from label whithout id but with "for" attribute?

```
<input type="radio" value="questao1" id="SimuladoQuestao1">
        <label for="SimuladoQuestao1">asa</label>
```

Thanks,
Celso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prototype has a very strong selector engine. This is one way of doing it:

```
$$('label[for="SimuladoQuestao1"]').first().update('New label')
```

See [details here](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar-dollar/)